# scala - Within a trait, refer to an object that extends it?

Tags: scala

It's common in data science to construct competitor models that extend common functionality like MaximumLikelihoodEstimation. For example, you may have something like this:

```
trait DataFrame
trait MaximumLikelihoodEstimation {
  case class MaximumLikelihoodFit(model: Model, params: Array[Double])
  def fit(data: DataFrame): MaximumLikelihoodFit = {
  val params: Array[Double] = ???
    // do math
    MaximumLikelihoodFit(
      model = this.getObject, // getObject doesn't exist... but something like this?
      params = params
    )
  }
}
trait Model // not important, implements things like pdf, cdf
object ModelA extends Model with MaximumLikelihoodEstimation
object ModelB extends Model with MaximumLikelihoodEstimation
object ModelC extends Model with MaximumLikelihoodEstimation
```

What should I replace `this.getObject` with to get the object that's calling `fit`? For example, I want `ModelA.fit` to return `MaximumLikelihoodFit(ModelA, params)`.

Comment: what's `getObject`?

Comment: Your question conflicts with the title. In the title you seem to ask for `self`-reference to `MaximumLikelihoodEstimation`, in the question you ask for "the object that's calling fit". So, which one do you want?

Comment: 1) you are missing `=` after `def fit ...` 2) you can't extend `object`s 3) reflection probably has nothing to do with it ; It doesn't compile, and the question is unclear. Please fix that.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin The latter. and thanks, updated based on your comments. It shouldn't compile though-- that's the point (I want something to replace the non-existent `getObject` method)

Comment: @NickResnick Thank you. Apparently, having an "almost compilable" (+- one line) example wasn't really necessary in this case, because SergGr has already guessed all possible correct solutions ;))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you probably want is called [Self-types](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/self-types.html). Following code compiles:

```
trait DataFrame
trait Model // not important, implements things like pdf, cdf

trait MaximumLikelihoodEstimation {
  self: Model => // this is the magic line!

  case class MaximumLikelihoodFit(model: Model, params: Array[Double])

  def fit(data: DataFrame): MaximumLikelihoodFit = {
    val params: Array[Double] = ???
    MaximumLikelihoodFit(
      model = this,
      params = params
    )
  }
}

object ModelA extends Model with MaximumLikelihoodEstimation
object ModelB extends Model with MaximumLikelihoodEstimation
object ModelC extends Model with MaximumLikelihoodEstimation
```

If for some reason that doesn't work for you, probably your only other choice is to introduce that `getObject` method explicitly. IMHO the way that results in the least typing is following:

```
trait DataFrame

trait ModelProvider {
  val model:Model
}
trait Model extends ModelProvider {
  override val model: Model = this
}


trait MaximumLikelihoodEstimation {
  self: ModelProvider =>

  case class MaximumLikelihoodFit(model: Model, params: Array[Double])

  def fit(data: DataFrame): MaximumLikelihoodFit = {
    val params: Array[Double] = ???
    MaximumLikelihoodFit(
      model = this.model,
      params = params
    )
  }
}

object ModelA extends Model with MaximumLikelihoodEstimation
object ModelB extends Model with MaximumLikelihoodEstimation
object ModelC extends Model with MaximumLikelihoodEstimation
```

Comment: awesome, self-type worked, thank you. Does this mean `this` inside MaximumLikelihoodEstimation will actually reference Model? Still learning scala's type system...

Comment: @NickResnick *At runtime*, it would reference the `Model` anyway, but with `{ this: Model => ... }`, the compiler knows *at compile time* that `this` will be of type `Model`, and everything type-checks. In principle, you could just force it to compile by casting to `Model`, and it would run. But this would be very brittle and unsafe.

Comment: @NickResnick, I think the test that would be interesting for you is to try to compile `object Test extends MaximumLikelihoodEstimation` (i.e. without `Model`) and see what the compiler would say.